# how do I align tilemap with grid in godot

Tags: godot4

I have a tilemap in which each tile is 16x16. And it aligns with the Y axis, but not with the X axis. How do I fix this?

[image]

you can see the square passing aligning with the Y axis(yellow line), but not with the X axis (purple line)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By default your `TileMap` (assuming you have not moved it) will be placed at the origin.

If there is no `Camera2D`, the origin will be the top-left corner of the screen. *If you add a `Camera2D`, it will be placed at the origin... So the origin will be at center of the screen. That can be gotcha.*

However what we are looking at the bottom of the screen.

---

Thus, the issue is that the tile size is not a divisor of the screen size.

As you probably know, you can set the size of the tiles in the `TileMap` in the inspector.

If you want to change the screen size, you can find it in Project Settings: `display/window/size/viewport_width` and `display/window/size/viewport_height`.

*You also want to be aware of `display/window/stretch/mode` and `display/window/stretch/aspect`. See [Multiple resolutions](https://docs.godotengine.org/en/stable/tutorials/rendering/multiple_resolutions.html).